# Is it possible to change the displayed name of the keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, indicator

I would like to change the displayed name of the keyboard layout indicator — for example, right now mine reads en, ru or uk which does not look nice on the panel. Is it possible?

Can I edit some configuration file and make it read English, Russian or Ukrainian?

Comment: I have found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=3507927) solution, but it have been four years, so from the fact that my xkb folder is empty I guess keyboard layout indicator display method have changed.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/940617/103599.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the abbreviations of layouts shown in keyboard layout indicator of GNOME panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940617/how-to-change-the-abbreviations-of-layouts-shown-in-keyboard-layout-indicator-of)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have a read through the [Community Documentation for custom keyboard layout definitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions).

> The basic keyboard mapping package is XKB. In current Ubuntus, the
>   default directory is not `/etc/X11/xkb` but rather `/usr/share/X11/xkb`.
>   Layouts are kept in the `symbols` directory therein: they are generally
>   named by a two letter country code associated with the language for
>   which the layout is designed.