# How to change the abbreviations of layouts shown in keyboard layout indicator of GNOME panel?

Tags: keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, indicator, ubuntu-gnome

The keyboard layout indicator in GNOME, which appears in the panel after adding more than one layouts, shows preassigned abbreviations for layouts. Is there a way to rename this abbreviations? For example I want to change **en** to **Eng** here:

[image]

If I'm not mistaken it can be done pretty easily in KDE.

*Distro:* Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Comment: I believe it's not possible due to GNOME wanting only two letters but I will look into it.

Comment: It also has something to do with xkbmap.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/209598/48372

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/451945/permanently-set-keyboard-layout-options-with-setxkbmap-in-gnome-unity

Comment: there is another method which is to use IBUS instead by changing the engine descriptions.  However, I don't used IBUS and I personally don't know how it works.

Comment: ✅ I made this extension for that:
https://github.com/jasursadikov/gnome-language-flags

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## This method only works with Xorg<sup>*</sup>

(***** *Update from the original asker:* It seems the changes made in an Xorg session persist after rebooting to a Wayland session.)

---

### Introduction

Basically, GNOME-Shell seem to be obtaining the abbreviations of the keyboard layouts from a configuration file ( `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`).  So to change them, we first need to open the configuration file in a text editor and then change them to whatever we want!

There are two different ways to do it.  Though the graphical interface which includes the mouse or the command line interface which is only the keyboard.

---

### Common first step

First open a terminal.

There is many way to do this.  This method is the simplistic. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> on your keyboard.  You will see a dialog box come up and type in `gnome-terminal` or the name of your terminal.  It should look like this now.

[image: Dialog1]

Now, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It should close and bring up an terminal.

[image: Blank Terminal]

Form here there are two ways: First the graphical way, or the Command interface.

---

## Graphical Method

2. Now type in

   ```
   sudo -i gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
   ```

   This is how it should look.

   [image: Terminal with filename1]
3. Now, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it should open the file in which we need to edit.  This is how it should look:

   [image: Gedit_1]
4. Now click on the bottom with the three dots. Highlighted in blue, then find and click on "*Find and Replace...*" Highlighted in lighter gray.

   [image]

   Now it should bring up an dialog

   [image: Dialog_2]
5. Now we can edit this file to change "en" to "Eng". This will change all of the layouts that uses "en"

   Now, type into the text-box with "Find" to the left of it with this `<shortDescription>en</shortDescription>`
   Next, with the textbook below it and text to the left that says "*Replace with*", type this in it `<shortDescription>Eng</shortDescription>`. Now it should look like this.

   [image: Dialog 2]

   However, if you only want to change one layout then you will need to find it individually instead of changing all of them.  I would just used the Find function to search for the name of it which needs to be spell exactly to find it.
6. Now click on the button that says "*Replace all*" now that dialog box should disappeared with it saying it's found and replace 9 or so occurrences.

   [image: Gedit_2]
7. Now save it by clicking on the save button highlighted in light gray.

   [image: Gedit_4]

   Now, notice that the asterisk in the title should go away like this.  If it didn't then it didn't save.

   [image: Gedit_1]
8. Restart your PC.  Now it should look like this.  Notice, that I did it with "eng" instead of "Eng"

   [image]

---

## Command line interface

2. Type in

   ```
   sudo sed -i -e 's/<shortDescription>en</shortDescription>/<shortDescription>Eng</shortDescription>/g' /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.
4. Type in your password.
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.
6. Restart your PC.

Comment: First I made a change (**en** to **Eng**) by the graphical method described in the answer in an Xorg session, and it worked. Then I rebooted and started a *GNOME on Wayland* session and the change I made still applied there (it showed **Eng** instead of **en**)!

Comment: It’s really hard to see what is actually going on with all these screenshots put in between the facts. The OP has 18k points here, it may just be possible he knows how to open a shell.

Comment: @MPi I made it for anyone.  Anyone that uses Ubuntu with Gnome at the time.  Even the newbies.  If you don't like the graphical way then you can do it by the Command line way.  I left two options for a reason.

Comment: @MPi Also when he asked the question and when I answer it.  He only had 5 points.

Comment: @MPi Proof https://i.imgur.com/rr0c9tn.png

Comment: Incredible – how did the OP do that in such a short time?

As to your answer: Even the command-line version contains the instructions to press the enter key. You got your upvote anyway.

Comment: @MPi Because it's still an step?

Comment: @MathCubes: I see you absolutely and continually fail to see my point. That’s OK. Different people have different needs.

Comment: @MPi To include a summary in the beginning of the post?  I never thought about doing that before.  If you want to edit my post to do that then go ahead.

Comment: @MPi When someone ask for a solution for a problem that involves some understand of the technical background of how its works.  It's means it's beyond their skill set or to their understanding.  Which is why I include step by step instructions with pictures because I don't want them to get confuse or mess something up.  

The asker was lucky because I been using Gnome-Shell for years and I had an idea on how it works.  I knew it must be store in a conf file and I figure that Gnome was getting it from a global file and it's just accord to me that X dealt with these things.  So I just look...

Comment: .. up the X conf files for the keyboard. It took me around 30 minutes, if I remember right. The only thing that I did not realized was it would work with Wayland as well. Its probably it's from Xwayland..

Comment: @MPi Better now?